# Enforce unique value per user including global ones

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application where users can create their own custom private tags but there're also some fixed system-wide common tags. Tags are stored in a database table, where common tags are those where `USER_ID` is `NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE TAG (
    TAG_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    TAG_NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    USER_ID INT,

    CONSTRAINT TAG_PK PRIMARY KEY (TAG_ID),

    CONSTRAINT TAG_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID)
    REFERENCES [USER] (USER_ID)
);
CREATE INDEX TAG_IDX1 ON TAG (USER_ID);
```

I want to enforce at DB level that tags are unique to each user, what means that:

- A user may only have one tag with a given name, but other customers may also have their own tags with such name.
- Common tags should count too, so users can't create a tag that's already a common one.

A simple index like this won't work because it only prevents dupes within groups (common tags an each user)—it's still possible to re-create common tags as user tags:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TAG_UK1 ON TAG (TAG_NAME, USER_ID);
```

I believe that SQL Server doesn't allow expressions in indexes, e.g.:

```
-- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COALESCE'.
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TAG_UK1 ON TAG (TAG_NAME, COALESCE(USER_ID, 'COMMON'));
```

Can you think of some other approach?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to rethink the architecture a little bit. This is a many to many type of relationship (with some additional caveats) that is nearly impossible to do with just two tables.

Comment: Guaranteeing uniqueness in this case through an index might not be doable -AFAIK, anyway- and it doesn't sound like you will take advantage of an index for performance reasons, either. Why don't you put this checks in a stored proc or a trigger?

Comment: @SeanLange I hadn't thought about it that way and it makes sense from DB design perspective. But considering I may also need to edit the administration tool and many other parts of the codebase, perhaps it's better to just allow dupes and tweak the UI to display them separately—that'd probably be acceptable for my precise use case.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need handle this with trigggers.

In the tag table if you insert or update a new global tag. You need to check for every user to see if he already have that tag and transform it to global

For example you have `Angular` as a tag but some users are way a head and create `Angular4`. When `Angular4` become a global tag you need to remove it from all users.

Same for creating a tag for an user, you can check if the global already have that tag and raise an error.

Comment: Common tags are hard-coded in the initial data set and they cannot be changed.

Comment: Doesn't change my answer. Adding tags for users can only be validated using triggers

Comment: Thank you. I probably had Oracle and its function-based indexes in mind when I came up with this brilliant design xD